# Multiple Watermark in same image same time

Tags: jquery, watermark

Currently I'm try to working with drag and drop watermark image using http://fmaz.developpez.com/proj/imgwatermark/demo.html this plugin.

But there is only 1 image watermark system. I didn't find any documentation for multiple watermark.

I want to add 2 watermark picture at a time.

There is Currently watermark image is "A" . "A" is movable anywhere inside image. I want to add another watermark on same image name "B" . is that possible? Any trick??

I tried to find on web and stackoverflow. Any clever tricks??

Thanks

[image: Watermark image screenshot]

Comment: if you can expand the water mark.. a single watermark with tabs and line breaks can be made to look like multiple ones.

Comment: Can you type in space in the watermark? and do a Ctrl+Enter?

Comment: "A" is a png image. not text

Comment: in that case, can you create a Png image with Transparency the same size as the original image?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

Cuttent watermark #id is watermarked and area is x & y.

I just create different area name

a, b & p, q for two image an set id watermarked. So all watermark show in same image.

Here is code:

```
$scope.posA = 80;
$scope.posB = 90;
$scope.posX = 5;
$scope.posY = 5;
$scope.posP = 150;
$scope.posQ = 100;
```

& other code is

```
          $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
                watermark_img: 'images/watermark.png',
                resizable: false,
                  x: $scope.posX,
                  y: $scope.posY,
                onChange: showCoords
            });

            $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
                watermark_img: 'images/watermark2.png',
                position:      'bottomcenter',
                resizable: false,
                  p: $scope.posP,
                  q: $scope.posQ,
                onChange: showCoords

            });

            $('#watermarked').Watermarker({
                watermark_img: 'images/watermark3.png',
                resizable: false,
                  a: $scope.posA,
                  b: $scope.posB,
                  w: '132px',
                  h: '20px',
                position: 'bottomleft',
                onChange: showCoords
            });


            function showCoords(c)
              {
                $scope.$parent.posA = c.a;
                $scope.$parent.posB = c.b;  
                $scope.$parent.posX = c.x;
                $scope.$parent.posY = c.y;
                $scope.$parent.posP = c.p;
                $scope.$parent.posQ = c.q;
              };
```

I implement code with my AngularJS App. So code is look like this.

Hope it will help people.